# Rounding float in ToString() function?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

So I have a form with a label which is supposed to display float value, the problem is that I need to have that number rounded to 2 decimal places whatever happens:

```
label1->Text = System::Convert::ToString( (float)((float)temperature/204.6) );
```

I tried looking for few hours but as I found there is no method for direct rounding of that beast equation and as far as I know no way to tell ToString() to round the thing to 2 decimals.

Is there any easy way to round the result to 2 decimal places inside ToString method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple to do:

```
String^ s = String::Format("{0:N2}", temperature/204.6);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any easy way to round the result to 2 decimal places inside ToString method?

No, not with `std::tostring()` and if you want to preserve trailing zeroes. Use a `std::ostringstream` with appropriate [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) instead:

```
 std::ostringstream oss;
 oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (temperature/204.6);
 label1->Text = oss.str();
```

Comment: `std::setprecision(2)`, I think

Comment: @Neil Yup, THX.

Answer (score 1):

Can't You multiple result by 100, cast to int, and then divide by 100 with casting to float?

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaScript equivalent of toFixed:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string ToFixed(double number, size_t digits)
{
    char format[10];
    char str[64];
    sprintf_s(format, "%%0.%zdf", digits);
    return std::string(str, sprintf_s(str, format, number));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ToFixed((double)12345 / 204.6, 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
60.34
```